# Impersonation fails when calling web method from SoapUI

Tags: c#, wcf, soapui, ntlm

I have a WCF self-hosted web service (hosted in my Windows service under Local System account). Web methods have `[OperationBehaviorAttribute(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]` attached. NTLM authentication is used.

In my web method's implementation I impersonate the caller and do some stuff. For this I use `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity`. If I don't give proper credentials when calling the web method then web service would return "401 Unauthorized".

When I call the method from Chrome then the windows identity and impersonation work great. I can create a new process under impersonated user, which will spawn in Windows session of that user (different from 0). Firefox also works when I add "localhost" string to `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` preference. But when SoapUI calls the method then this windows identity is not set up properly. Web method is called, so NTLM works to a degree, but it just doesn't work properly. A call to `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Owner.IsAccountSid()` returns false (`Owner` is not a user account, but built-in "Administrators" group). Creating a new process while impersonated would create it in Windows session 0.

I've looked into HTTP communication with Wireshark, and NTLM handshake looks different between Chrome and SoapUI. No idea what to do with that information though.

How to make SoapUI to work properly with my web service and NTLM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know how to fix the problem with WCF I switched to Web API and OWIN, and now I have a working solution.